# Is it legal to record a conversation in Massachusetts?

Tags: united-states, recording, massachusetts

If you are physically present in a room where conversation takes place, is it legal to digitally record the conversation?

Please refer to the following cases:

- When you are an active party
- When you are a passive listener
- When you are passive, but the conversation specifically regards yourself
- When the other party(s) know and agree to the recording
- When the other party(s) know and do not agree to the recording
- When the other party(s) do not know

Answer (score 2):

Massachusetts has one of the most restrictive laws in the USA on SECRETLY recording any conversation.  Other than that, you can record a conversation, assuming you have proof (if necessary for a criminal defense) that everyone speaking has knowledge that it's being recorded.

For instance, turning on your cellphone to record the conversation during a traffic stop, without the police officer's knowledge, would be a felony.

See, e.g., Commonwealth v. Jackson (1976), Commonwealth v. Hyde (2001), and cf. Glik v. Cunniffe, et al. (2011). MGL ch. 272, s.99.

Comment: Thanks. What about video recording (no audio)? Is placing hidden cameras in the house legal? What if I want to guard against child abuse by a caregiver?

Comment: Video laws are tied more to the "expectation of privacy" under the circumstances.  Also, a hidden camera cannot possibly "guard against child abuse".

Comment: Mmmm... I guess technically you're right - it can't "guard" against that, but I think my intention was clear - you suspect you babysitter and want to find out what's going on there when you're away.

Comment: "For instance, turning on your cellphone to record the conversation during a traffic stop, without the police officer's knowledge, would be a felony." - Are you sure?  See https://www.aclu-nh.org/sites/default/files/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Order-of-Dismissal.pdf .  It's from another state, but in the same circuit.

Comment: @DM Yes, it's not a very persuasive authority in MA when a state court in a different state interprets the Constitutionality of its own state law (RSA 570-1:2) versus an MGL (ch. 272 s. 99) having dissimilar elements, being enforced in MA. I haven't thoroughly researched whether any MA courts have discounted the MGL's blanket prohibition on "secret" interception of audio of others, when narrowly applied to acts of public servants in public.